# Excel formula to calculate diff b/w 1st value and last value in a column (Excel)?

Tags: vb.net, excel, excel-formula, vba

I have the following columns :   (Using Excel Formula)

```
     A            B
  ------------------------
1 |  Date     |   Value  |
  ------------------------
2 | 8/20/2011 |   92.8   |
3 | 8/21/2011 |   92.4   |
4 | 8/22/2011 |   91.8   |
5 | 8/23/2011 |   90.7   |
6 | 8/24/2011 |   91.1   |
7 | 8/25/2011 |          |
8 | 8/26/2011 |          |
9 | 8/27/2011 |          |
  ------------------------
```

> I want to calculate the difference between 1st Value (B2) and last Value (last populated row in column B)

**Edited :**

Using formula :  `=B2-B6` is not what's required.  (I want diff in Cell C2)

I want when the user enters the value in B7 it automatically shows the difference between B2  and B7, when he populates B8 then it shows the diff between B2 and B8 and so on..

> I don't want some direct method to do this in Excel and not by iterating all values to check the last value. Please suggest the best method to this in Excel.

This is more of a logic problem !

**A Pure Excel solution is welcome, I can do that manually.**

**Edited:**
Using Excel formula !

I hope I explained my problem properly..

Comment: Shows the difference where? In another column?

Comment: Nothing wrong in iterating, its like I think this is a very common task to do, so there should some direct method to do this.
May be a more clever formula.

Comment: @Tim I have edited the question, to show where to have the diff.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the headers are in A1 and B1, and your table is A2:B9 for instance, use the formula:

```
=$B$2-OFFSET($B$2,COUNTA($B$2:$B$9)-1,0,1,1)
```

Comment: +1.  One thing to consider is that all values from the first through to the latest one must be populated for this to work.  If there are any gaps, it will calculate the wrong value.

Answer (score 2):

To find the last number in a column you can use `VLOOKUP` on a single column where 1E+99 is the *lookup_value* and the optional *range_lookup* is left to the default. The data does not have to be sorted.

[image: last number with VLOOKUP]

The formula in C2 is `=VLOOKUP(1E+99,$B$2:$B$99,1)-B2`. Similarly, you can locate the last non-blank alphabetic value with `=VLOOKUP("zzzzz",$E$2:$E$99,1)` (example in F2).

To find the last non-blank value where there are mixed alphabetic and numeric values, use `INDEX` and apply `MAX` to `MATCH`, e.g. `=INDEX(E2:E99,MAX(IFERROR(MATCH(1E+99,E2:E99),0),IFERROR(MATCH("zzzz",E2:E99),0)))`. Any of these formulas could easily be adjusted to return a value from another column corresponding to the last value in the lookup column.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you are not looking for a *pure* Excel solution but you can use it a different way >> you can add an Excel formula with vb/vba.

Something like `=B7-$B$2` is the formula needed.

Thus, you can do something like:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B:B")) Is Nothing Then
    Target.Offset(0, 1).Formula = "=" & Target.Address & "-$B$2"
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: A pure Excel solution will do. I can manually implement that.
No Problems.

Answer (score 0):

Another less elegant way to do this with Excel formulas alone, would be to use a helper column, which is a telescoping series.

In column C2, enter 0.
In columns C3, use the formula

```
=IF(B3="",0,B2-B3)
```

Copy down the length of the table.
At the bottom, sum everything in the helper column.

Comment: Your previous answer was what was required. Only 1 cell should have shown the net change in value. So, this is not required. Anyways thanks for contributing.